# Custom object list can't add object at runtime gives "Nullpointer Exception"

Tags: list, jsp, nullpointerexception, dynamicobject, tobjectlist

I am facing some problem while creating one list of custom type objectlist and adding some object in that list.
I have one `advertise` object list

```java
public int ajax_GenerateReports(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) throws Exception {

    log.info("ajax_Generate Reports Enter");

    String strcamp_id =  request.getParameter("CMD");

    log.info("ajax_Generate Reports Enter"+strcamp_id);

    long camp_id = Long.parseLong(strcamp_id);

    log.info("camp_ID:-"+ camp_id);

    int iResult = 1;

    List<campaign_map_adv> camp_map_adv_List = null;

    List<advertise> adv_List = null;

    camp_map_adv_List = campaign_map_advLocalServiceUtil.getAllCamp_Map_Adv_By_campID(camp_id);

    log.info("CAMPIAGN MAP OBJECT : - "+ camp_map_adv_List.get(0));
    log.info("CAMPIAGN MAP OBJECT List Count : - "+ camp_map_adv_List.size());

    if(!camp_map_adv_List.isEmpty()) { //Search For Each Camp entry in camp_map Adv

        for (campaign_map_adv campaign_map_advitem : camp_map_adv_List) {                
            //add each advertise to temporary list file of advertise from camp_map_adv
            advertise temp_ad = advertiseLocalServiceUtil.getadvertise(campaign_map_advitem.getAdvId());

            adv_List.add(temp_ad);
        }

    }
    //          

    ////////////////
    System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
    System.out.println(java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless());
    System.out.println("IN GENRATE REPORTS ");

    System.out.println("IN GENRATE LIST " +adv_List.size());

    JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(adv_List);

    System.out.println(" bean collection " + beanCollectionDataSource.getRecordCount());

    System.out.println("Test!!");

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager
            .fillReport(
                    "C:/liferay/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/eMenuAdvertise-portlet/src_reports/report3.jasper",
                    new HashMap<String, Object>(), beanCollectionDataSource);

    System.out.println(" report path ");
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint, "c:/liferay/report.html");

    ///////////////

    log.info("ajax_GenerateReports Leave");

    return iResult;
}
```

From the following line onwards my code has runtime error after inserting first object:

```
advertise temp_ad = advertiseLocalServiceUtil.getadvertise(campaign_map_advitem.getAdvId());

adv_List.add(temp_ad);
```

so if anyone can guide me ...

Stack Trace:-

```
18:32:21,719 INFO  [http-bio-8080-exec-56][RestaurantPortlet:2311] serveResource Start
18:32:21,746 INFO  [http-bio-8080-exec-56][RestaurantPortlet:2322] Resource Id - generate_report
18:32:21,747 INFO  [http-bio-8080-exec-56][RestaurantPortlet:2225] ajax_Generate Reports Enter
18:32:21,747 INFO  [http-bio-8080-exec-56][RestaurantPortlet:2228] ajax_Generate Reports Enter22901
18:32:21,747 INFO  [http-bio-8080-exec-56][RestaurantPortlet:2230] camp_ID:-22901
18:32:21,778 INFO  [http-bio-8080-exec-56][RestaurantPortlet:2237] CAMPIAGN MAP OBJECT : - {id=22902, campaignId=22901, advId=18726, restId=15101, isactive=true, adtypeId=4}
18:32:21,779 INFO  [http-bio-8080-exec-56][RestaurantPortlet:2238] CAMPIAGN MAP OBJECT : - 7
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at emenu.advertise.portlet.RestaurantPortlet.ajax_GenerateReports(RestaurantPortlet.java:2248)
    at emenu.advertise.portlet.RestaurantPortlet.serveResource(RestaurantPortlet.java:2437)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:118)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:531)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeResource(InvokerPortletImpl.java:626)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.serveResource(InvokerPortletImpl.java:436)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processPortletRequest(LayoutAction.java:1075)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:719)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:176)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:560)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:537)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:294)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:294)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:241)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:246)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:80)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:216)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:187)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:167)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:167)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:187)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: You state "From Following line my code having runtime error after inserting first object", does this mean that you can successfully add at least one "advertise" object into your "adv_List"?

Comment: Can you provide the relevant stack-trace of the exception? Thanks

Comment: no@rhod i just get exception before adv)List.add(temp_ad);

Comment: prakash.i dont have stack trace right now.can provide by tomorrow mornig.sorry for that.but what i want to ask is that beacuse when adv_list (object list) is null and because of that it cant add the object?

Comment: @PrakashK please see my updated question at last have put stacktrace.please see it

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745325/custom-object-list-cant-add-object-at-runtime-gives-nullpointer-exception#comment18896791_13745325).

So taking this into account the line  `RestaurantPortlet.java:2248` in the stacktrace would be:

```
adv_List.add(temp_ad); // I m guessing this might be the line: 2248
```

I think it is just oversight that you might have missed instantiating the `adv_List`, you currently have:

```
List<advertise> adv_List = null;
```

and after this there is nothing and directly the call `adv_List.add(temp_ad);`, instead we can have:

```
List<advertise> adv_List = new ArrayList<advertise>();
```

I think this should solve it, it was quite simple :-)

<sub>***Unrelated to the question:*** It is strange to see your class-names as lower-case (like `advertise`, `campaign_map_adv` etc) this makes it difficult to read and is not the standard java convention. Because of this you have to use variables with underscores which is another pain to read.</sub>

Comment: ya i know..but as i have created my entity name with lower-case..its generate all class with lower case..this is my first porltet and ddnt know that giving entity name as lower case will create name in lower case for class to that ..

Comment: can we have chat for while have some issue ..so i if u have time then please

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/20749/for-date-time-format-in-java?tab=general